# Check from_date before to_date and to_date after from_date, also both dates before today in laravel nova validation

Tags: laravel, validation, date, laravel-nova

```
return [

            Date::make('From Date')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:'.date('Y-m-d').''),

            Date::make('To Date')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:'.date('Y-m-d').''),

        ];
```

Above is my code, I have the following validation requirement:

**From Date**

1. Date format Y-m-d
2. In the past
3. Before to date

**To Date**

1. Date format Y-m-d
2. In the past
3. After From date

How can I add both the validations together in laravel nova field make rules properties? Both as in date before to_date and date before today as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach all the Laravel validation rules to Nova resource fields.

Try below code,

Validation reference : [After date](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-after), [Before date](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-before)

```
return [
    Date::make('From Date') 
        ->sortable() 
        ->rules('required', 'date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:today', 'before:to_date'), 

    Date::make('To Date') 
        ->sortable() 
        ->rules('required', 'date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', 'before:today', 'after:from_date'), 
 ];
```

Comment: The field is To Date, will that work with to_date ? I tried with before:To Date, but that sometimes work, sometimes it fails. Not sure why.

Comment: @ShraddhaBanerjee `to_date` should work, if that is the model attribute name. Can you provide some test cases which worked & not worked

Comment: I was using the field name "To Date", "From Date" whereas I was supposed to use "to_date", "from_date". Thanks @Saumini Navaratnam :)